# How to select the deepest last class inside nested classes?

Tags: css, nested, styles

I have nested class like below

[image]

I need to access the last mat-nested-tree-node class, i tried like below

```
.mat-nested-tree-node:last-child ul {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: -41px;
}
```

But it is applying styles to all mat-nested-tree-node classes. How can i select only the last child?

This is my editor url https://amarrkydlnk.angular.stackblitz.io

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: use :nth-child(n) concept, and write the css for it, so that it works specifically for that class only

Answer (score 0):

If you want to target a child of a div you can do it like `.mat-nested-tree-node > .mat-nested-tree-node-child > .mat-nested-tree-node-child-next{}` and so on and so on.